# linux nasm assembly dwtoa

Tags: linux, function, assembly, x86, nasm

I am stuck on a practice problem where I need to read in an integer, add 1 to it and print out the result. On this question: [linux nasm assembly print all numbers from zero to 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097906/linux-nasm-assembly-print-all-numbers-from-zero-to-100), user Gunner mentioned dwtoa. I'm assuming that that is a callable function. So what is this dwtoa function? And if it is in fact a callable function, where can I get it (by get I mean how can I implement it in my code?)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/202395-masm-adding-numbers/

Comment: When I try and compile with `nasm -f elf -g -F stabs`, it says `error: symbol dwtoa undefined`. So where is this `dwtoa` located in nasm?

Comment: http://forum.nasm.us/index.php?topic=1042.0

Comment: instead of asking where to get dwtoa, you should be asking yourself how to convert a number to its printable ascii version.  look at an ascii table and notice the difference between 0 and "0" ascii codes... now how would you convert one to another?  if you don't care about these details, why use assembly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, ya gotta write it... or borrow one somebody's already written. The latter is easier (the C library has functions like this, and it's easy to call from asm), but the former is more "fun". (if you like that kind of thing - hey, some people do crossword puzzles)

The `div` instruction is very slow. There's a better way to do it based on multiplying by the reciprocal and "back multiplying". It's quite complicated. We'll wait for `div`. :)

`div ebx`

If we had arranged to have our number, say 1234, in `eax` and 10 in `ebx`, we would now have 123 in `eax` and 4 in `edx` (`ebx` remains unchanged). Actually, we'd want to have 0 in `edx` before the `div`...

`xor edx, edx`

`div ebx`

As you know, we can convert the number 4 to the character '4' by adding the character '0' (or 48 decimal or 30h). Now we've got something we can print! But we're not quite ready to print it yet - we're getting the digits backwards. There are several ways to deal with this. I think the simplest is to `push` 'em on the stack and `pop` 'em off in the correct order. Another way is to go ahead and put 'em in the buffer backwards and do a "string reverse" at the end. Another way is to start at the "end" of the buffer and work toward the front (decrement your index into the buffer after each character instead of incrementing it). This can mean that you're not quite at the beginning of the buffer when you run out of digits. We can use that to our advantage - right justified numbers look good if you're going to print 'em in a column. You could fill with leading zeros, too (the character '0', not the number 0) if you think that looks good (I don't).

In any case, we've got '4' stashed away safely. Loop back  and `div` again (making `edx` zero first!). Now we've got 12 in `eax` and 3 in `edx`. Do something with the 3 and go back to `div` again. 1 in `eax` and 2 in `edx`. Again, and `eax` is zero (`edx` is 1) - at that point we're done! We can skip the last `div` if we compare `eax` to 9 - if it's less, we can get our final (first to be printed) digit from `al` instead of `dl`. Simpler to do it the same way every time...

```
; mov eax, the number
; mov edi, the buffer (at least resb 10, please)
; call dwtoa
; mov edx, eax ; count
; mov ecx, buffer
; print it

dwtoa:
    xor ecx, ecx ; for a counter
    mov ebx, 10
pushloop:
    xor edx, edx ; or mov edx, 0
    div ebx
    add edx, '0'
    push edx
    inc ecx ; count it
    test eax, eax ; or cmp eax, 0
    jnz pushloop
    mov eax, ecx ; we'll return the count in eax
poploop:
    pop edx
    mov [edi], dl
    inc edi
    loop poploop
    ret
```

That's off the top of my head (not cut-and-pasted), and may have errors. It's pretty sloppy - trashes registers that C would like preserved - doesn't return a zero-terminated string as C would like... but we're not using C so we don't care! :)

Feel free to improve it to your taste, or try a different method.

Unless you've got one, you'll want a "atoi" (or "atodw" to use the same naming convention), to convert the text the user enters to a number. Same idea, but we subtract '0' from the character, multiply the "result so far" by ten, and add in the new digit... until done.

```
;-------------------
; atoi - converts string to (unsigned!) integer
; expects: buffer in edx
; returns: number in eax
atoi:
    xor eax, eax        ; clear "result"
.top:
    movzx ecx, byte [edx]
    inc edx

    cmp ecx, byte 0
    jz .done
    cmp ecx, byte 10
    jz .done

    cmp ecx, byte '0'
    jb .invalid
    cmp ecx, byte '9'
    ja .invalid

    ; we have a valid character - multiply
    ; result-so-far by 10, subtract '0'
    ; from the character to convert it to
    ; a number, and add it to result.

    lea eax, [eax + eax * 4]
    lea eax, [eax * 2 + ecx - '0']

    jmp short .top
.invalid:
    stc
.done:
    ret
;--------------
```

That one's cut-and-pasted so "should" work. It, too, could be improved. Uses an "interesting" way to multiply by ten and add in the new character converted to a number. At this point, the "work" of your program consists of:
`add eax, 1`
Should give you something to work with, anyway. Have fun! :)

Comment: Thanks alot, Frank. Very comprehensive.