# Result is false in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86

Hello I had written this code in assembly language:

```
.data
integer:
.long 0
.text
.globl  _start
_start: 
  movl $3, %eax
  movl $0, %ebx
  movl $integer, %ecx
  movl $5, %edx
  int $0x80
  movl %ecx, %ebx
end: 
  movl $1, %eax 
  int $0x80
```

I want the input value written to %ebx register. It doesn't work. When I enter 4, the %ebx register returns 147. I assembled and linked with these commands:

```
sukur@sukur-System-Product-Name:~/Desktop$ as program.s -o program.o
sukur@sukur-System-Product-Name:~/Desktop$ ld program.o -o program
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: In the future, please format your code!

Comment: I suspect that you meant to move the value that `%ecx` points to into `%ebx`. Perhaps start troubleshooting there?

Comment: David is right, as well `Int 0x80/eax=3` syscall doesn't read text and convert it into integers. It reads text as ASCII and stores it into a buffer. You must manually convert the ASCII characters into an integer and store that in the register _EBX_.

Comment: "the result is false" isn't correct. most probably it's not what you expected, but it's right. It's just the program simply does what you told it to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linux nasm assembly dwtoa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266757/linux-nasm-assembly-dwtoa)

Comment: It's not an ideal duplicate candidate, but I didn't have much luck finding another question where the problem was mistaken assumptions about what `read(2)` does.