# NASM - how to print a number using int 080h?

Tags: assembly, stdout, nasm

I'm writing a program in NASM that takes in a string and counts how many letters are in it, and then prints out the results, and I have to use the 080h interupt to do all the writing and reading. I keep a count of the letters in a label in the .data section:

```
lett:   db 0                            ; letter counter
```

and then I increment it when I find a letter:

```
inc     byte [lett]
```

but when I go to write to STDOUT, nothing shows up, and I'm not sure if I'm using 080h correctly:

```
    mov     eax, SYSCALL_WRITE      ; write the letter count to stdout
    mov     ebx, STDOUT             ;
    mov     ecx, lett               ;
    mov     edx, 1                  ;
    int     080h                    ;
```

I know EDX needs to contain the length of the buffer to read from, which I assume is 1, since I set lett to point to one byte, initialized at 0. Is there something wrong here?

Comment: You need to convert the number to string first. If it's a single digit only, you can do `add byte [lett], '0'`.

Comment: Although you are using NASM,you can get an idea from the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14106921/3857942) to a similar question. You have to convert the number into a string. Most implementations continually divide the original number by the base (10), add 0x30 (ascii char '0') to it and then store that to a buffer. You have to account for the fact the numbers will appear in reverse order.The answer in the link I provided places each character onto the stack directly and then passes a stack pointer to the `int 0x80` call.You will have to convert the code from at&t syntax to intel.

Comment: @Jester thank you, that fixed it right away, and thanks >Michael, I did see that-- I just barely know enough NASM to do this, I got a bit confused looking at the at&t syntax, but I'll look over it again

Comment: @jester is correct Ben, however heed the warning `If it's a single digit only` so his idea works for 0-9 but try to print 10 or higher and observe what happens.

Comment: For the most part the at&t syntax reverses the operands. and each register is prefixed by `%` symbol. `mov %ax, %bx` for instance would be `mov bx, ax` (operands reversed)` in Intel syntax. There are other things that are different but if you can get your mind around the operands going the other direction you should be able to figure it out pretty quickly.

Comment: @MichaelPetch, ah that does cause problems, `Enter a string: hhhhhhhhhh` gives me `There were : alphabetic characters.`, so it goes over since theres no '10' in ascii. Lucky for me, I've been guaranteed no more than 9 characters, since I'm just starting out. And thanks, that syntax seems to make more sense, since it goes in the same direction as we read it

Comment: If your professor doesn't mind you calling the libc `printf` function it can be done much nicer. But I have a feeling that you'd get a poor grade with that solution.

Comment: If you are limited to 9 characters great. Possibly in the next assignment he'll ask you to support more than 9 ;-)

Comment: Yea, I hope, this is our intro so we're forced to use the kernel interrupts, soon I imagine things won't be so ugly

Comment: Try redirecting the stdout to a file and using `od` command to see if your program is writing some data.

Comment: If you can use libc, converting the integer to string via `sprintf` and printing it via system call may be a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print a number in ASCII string, you have to convert the number to a string.

This will work for nonnegative number:

```
    ; dummy to tell the program the end of data
    push -1
    ; set the number to convert
    xor eax, eax
    mov al, [lett]
    ; convert the number to string (sequence of character)
convert_loop:
    xor edx, edx
    mov ebx, 10
    div ebx
    add edx, '0'
    push edx
    test eax, eax
    jnz convert_loop
    ; print the converted string
print_loop:
    cmp dword [esp], 0
    jl print_loop_end ; break when -1 is found
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, esp
    mov edx, 1
    int 080h
    pop eax ; move on next character
    jmp print_loop
print_loop_end:
    pop eax ; clean -1
```

**UPDATE:** Another version without using `push / pop` instruction:

```
section .bss
    ; 32-bit unsigned integer won't be longer than 10 digits in decimal
    strtonum_convert_buffer resb 12

section .text

    ; dummy to tell the program the end of data
    mov ecx, strtonum_convert_buffer
    mov byte [ecx], 0
    ; set the number to convert
    xor eax, eax
    mov al, [lett]
    ; convert the number to string (sequence of character)
convert_loop:
    xor edx, edx
    mov ebx, 10
    div ebx
    add edx, '0'
    inc ecx
    mov [ecx], dl
    test eax, eax
    jnz convert_loop
    ; print the converted string
print_loop:
    cmp byte [ecx], 0
    je print_loop_end ; break when 0 is found
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    ; there is already the pointer to the character on ecx
    mov edx, 1
    int 080h
    dec ecx ; move on next character
    jmp print_loop
print_loop_end:
```

Comment: Thanks I can get that general drift of that, and sort of understand, but I haven't even gotten to the stack yet, so the popping and pushing is very new to me, just visually, but it was the ascii conversion I missing

Comment: Nothing special. `push` and `pop` work the same way they do everywhere else. You push `x` onto the stack, then push `y`onto the stack. When you call `pop` you will first get `y` back, then when you call `pop` again you get `x` back. Works just like any stack. Say, `stack` is a catchy name -- bet it gets used for all sorts of .... stacks `:)`